# ChoiceGroup on J2me always rendered with the first index selected

Tags: java-me

Is there a way,using the native j2me choice group to always display it with no index selected?..note: The choice can be highlighted, but not necessarily selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ChoiceGroup objects of type **MULTIPLE** and **setSelectedFlags** method like this:

```
public class myMIDlet extends MIDlet implements ItemStateListener ... {
...
ChoiceGroup cg = new ChoiceGroup("cg", Choice.MULTIPLE);
Form form;
...
public myMIDlet(){

cg.append("Element1", null);
cg.append("Element2", null);
cg.append("Element3", null);
cg.setSelectedFlags(new boolean[]{false, false, false});
form = new Form("form", new Item[]{cg});
form.setItemStateListener(this);
}
...
public void itemStateChanged (Item item){
cg.setSelectedFlags(new boolean[]{false, false, false});
}   
}
```

setSelectedFlags method Attempts to set the selected state of every element in the ChoiceGroup.For ChoiceGroup objects of type MULTIPLE, this sets the selected state of every element in the Choice. An arbitrary number of elements may be selected.
itemStateChanged(Item item) called when internal state of an Item has been changed by the user.